# Spring Injecting mock object then injecting result object into another class

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, cucumber, mockito, integration-testing

I feel like this should be possible and not too difficult, but I am unable to find similar situations and nothing I have tried has been successful. The situation is as follows:

I am writing cucumber tests using cucmber-jvm, spring, Mockito. I have three classes (A, B, C), one is the endpoint (Class C) which handles some database calls that in the end I will mock, the other two rely on each other (I'll be more clear soon) and I use Dependency Injections instead of setter methods. So the goal is to mock Class C and inject it into Class B (Easy Enough). Now I want to take the resulting Class B with the embedded Class C Mock and inject that into Class A. That is where I am stuck.

```
    Class A () {
      function doStuff() {}
    }

    Class B () {
      @Inject
      A a;

      function doThingsWithClassA() {}
    }

    Class C () {
      @Inject
      B b;

      function doThingsWithClassB() {
        b.DoThingsWithClassA();
      }
    }
```

So I have my basic classes that inject A into B and B into C which works fine in deployment. What I am trying to do is something like the following:

```
    @ContextConfiguration("classpath*:cucumber.xml") // Have this but not 
    sure if necessary at this point

    Class Test() {
       @Mock
       A a;

       @InjectMocks //Inject A
       @Spy //Ideally this would set this object to be injected into c
       B b;

       @InjectMocks //Inject B that is Spied
       C c;

       @Before
   public void setup() {
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

    }
```

And then be able to carry out my tests. Thus ensuring when I call c.doThingWithClassB it uses the injected Class b, so that in that method when b.doThingsWithClassA is called it hits the mocked object. This way I can simply use when(a.doStuff()).thenReturn(Insert_Pre_Populated_Object_Here) then Classes B and C that are not mocked can do their functions as intended.

I have tried Injecting in every which way, Autowiring (though I don't think that is appropriate here), and creating beans in the cucumber.xml.

I do not want to mock Class B as that would defeat the purpose of the tests. These tests are required in cucumber for this project. I have already Unit tested everything so just dropping the cucumber isn't an option .

Any help or direction to go for help is appreciated.